# Hibernate criteria group by date without time

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, date-formatting

This code give me a list of two items Datetime and count. But I need group it by date without time.

Can anyone give me a clue how to do it? Thanks!

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Parcel.class);

    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList(); 

        projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("dateCreated"));
        projectionList.add(Projections.rowCount());

    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);


    List<Object[]> results = criteria.list();
```

Result:

2013-04-27 11:08:00.0 | 32

2013-04-27 11:10:00.0 | 5

2013-04-28 15:03:27.0 | 12

I need:

2013-04-27 | 37

2013-04-28 | 12

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may find [Projections#sqlGroupProjection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#sqlGroupProjection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%5B%5D%29) method useful. It allows you to employ an SQL function `date()` that extracts `Date` form a `DateTime` column. Basically, instead of calling

```
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("dateCreated"));
```

use

```
projectionList.add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date(dateCreated) as createdDate", "createdDate", new String[] { "createdDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }));
```

Comment: Works great, but I had to replace the name of the entity field (`dateCreated` in your example) with the column name (`date_created` in your example). If I don’t do that, it complains that the column *in lower case*(?) (`datecreated` in your example) doesn’t exist.